# How to set actions url if custom actions are set programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

when I am using normal custom actions from xml it has:

```
<UrlAction Url="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}&amp;SPItemUrl={ItemUrl}" />
```

and its working fine, but when I am using

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserCustomAction _customAction = web.UserCustomActions.Add();
_customAction.RegistrationType = UserCustomActionRegistrationType.ContentType;
_customAction.RegistrationId = _guidOfCreatedCT;
_customAction.Location = "EditControlBlock";
_customAction.Sequence = 450;
_customAction.Title = "TEST";
string rrr =AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToString();
_customAction.Url = "~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}&amp;SPItemUrl={ItemUrl}";
_customAction.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

this url is not working. I dont know how to format this one, I tried everything and still any ideas. Someone can help me ?

This is autohosted app for Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `&amp;` to replace **&** in any XML structure, but you don't need to use `&amp;` in the code behind...

Comment: the problem is that whenever i add some url for example this button is on site google.pl, then if i set custom actions url to google.pl then it make url "google.pl/google.pl

Comment: Do you have this problem when you add it by XML?

Comment: not, only with code behind in post. this code make this custom actions everything is fine witout... url...

Answer (score 0):

Simply try using http:// or https:// in front of your custom url. Otherwise SharePoint will think that the action url is within SharePoint and so it will automatically generate a site relative url.